# Shellsort: Write NASM code from C

Tags: c, sorting, assembly, nasm, shellsort

I am trying to convert a C function to NASM in 32-bit.

Here is the C function

```
void shellsort (int *A, int n)
{
    int gap, i, j, temp;
    for (gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /=2)
    {
        for (i= gap; i<n; i++)
        {
            for  (j=i-gap; j>=0 && A[j] > A[j+gap]; j-=gap)
            {
                temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j+gap]
                A[j+gap] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have done so far

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

SECTION .data

SECTION .bss

SECTION .text

extern printf

global sort

sort:

    push ebp                            ;set up stack frame
    mov ebp, esp

    sub esp, 0x10                       ;assign 16byte space for local variables

firstloop:

    mov eax, [ebp+8]                    ;moves value of n into eax
    mov edx, 0                          ;prepares for division, remainder init
    mov ecx, 2                          ;divisor

    div ecx                             ;division, store gap in eax

    cmp eax, 0                          ;compare if gap with zero
    jle firstloopDone                   ;firstloopDone

firstloopDone:

    div ecx
    jmp done

secondloop:

    mov ecx, eax                        ;copy value of gap into ecx, i=gap
    cmp ecx, [ebp+8]                    ;compare i with 1st parameter n

    jge secondloopDone                  ;jump to secondloop if greater-equal
    inc ecx                             ;increment i
    jmp thirdloop                       ;jump to thirdloop

secondloopDone:

    inc ecx                             ;increment i
    jmp firstloop                       ;jump to firstloop

thirdloop:

    mov edx, ecx                        ;save i value
    sub ecx, eax                        ;subtract gap from i and store in ecx

    cmp ecx, 0                          ;compare j with zero
    jl thirdloopDone                    ;if not j>=0, then skip to end of loop

    cmp [ebp+12+ecx], [ebp+12+ecx+eax]  ;compare A[j] and A[j+gap]
    jle thirdloopDone
    sub ecx, eax                        ;subtract gap from j and store in ecx
    jmp swap

thirdloopDone:

    sub ecx, eax                        ;j-gap
    jmp secondloop                      ;jump to second loop

swap:

    mov edx, [ebp+12+ecx]               ;copy A[j] to temp
    mov [ebp+12+ecx], [ebp+12+ecx+eax]  ;A[j]=A[j+gap]
    mov [edp+12+ecx+eax], edx           ;A[j+gap]= temp
    jmp thirdloop

done:

    leave                               ;destroy stack frame
    ret
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work. 
The error message says:

"error: beroset-p-603-invalid effective address"

at line 58 (thirdloop)

`cmp [ebp+12+ecx], [ebp+12+ecx+eax]`

and at line 71 (swap)

`mov edx, [ebp+12+ecx]`

I understand that this may be the wrong method. But from the nested loop in C code, I have too many variables to keep so I cant spare any of the registers.

Also, I suspect I may not have a proper understanding of the stack frame, which may show in my code.

Any help, or bug-discovery, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: _"I have too many variables to keep so I cant spare any of the registers"_. Save one or more registers on the stack temporarily, or use a memory variable.

Comment: Also, division by 2 is equivalent to a right-shift by 1 in base-2. This should simplify your division routines a little.

Comment: Michael, I tried using stack but because of the loop I couldn't keep track of all the push and the pops. I used registers only.
Daniel, thanks for the tip! that really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't have enough registers to play with but you don't even use EBX, ESI, nor EDI. You made provisions for local variables yet you don't use any.

```
firstloop:
 mov eax, [ebp+8]                    ;moves value of n into eax
 mov edx, 0                          ;prepares for division, remainder init
 mov ecx, 2                          ;divisor
 div ecx                             ;division, store gap in eax
```

The previous code does not need the division. Simplify it with a shift operation. `shr eax,1`

The next code will always terminate. Use `jle done`

```
 cmp eax, 0                          ;compare if gap with zero
 jle firstloopDone                   ;firstloopDone
firstloopDone:
 div ecx
 jmp done
```

Aren't parameters pushed from right to left?

```
 mov ebx, [ebp+8]   ;pointer to array A
firstloop:
 mov eax, [ebp+12]  ;number of elemnets n
```

You would typically have to code

```
swap:
 mov  edx, [ebx+ecx*4]  ;TEMP=A[j]
 add  ecx,eax
 xchg edx, [ebx+ecx*4]  ;Swap A[j+gap] with TEMP
 sub  ecx, eax
 mov  [ebx+ecx*4], edx  ;A[j]=TEMP
 jmp  thirdloop
```

Comment: I re-did the entire code and it works now. Thanks for the help!